# Android native development - using bootstrap table grides

Tags: android, twitter-bootstrap

I was reading on twitter bootstrap grides and i saw that reactive native uses it.  realizing that reactive native is html css . but i was wondering if there is a way to standard align items using bootstrap in native android development ? Would everything have to be a webview to do this ? could it be done with xml ?  or could bootstrap grides be  something that a UX team would use to align the layout and present it to developer to implement.

http://bootstrapdocs.com/v2.0.2/docs/

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, please avoid WebView (embedding html/css code in Android project). It makes app's UX laggy and exploits app's security issues (cross-site scripting). Please always try to find native alternatives.
2. In your particular use case, you have a look at Android's [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html).

Hope this helps

Comment: good point about the native better. but i was referring to this:  http://bootstrapdocs.com/v2.0.2/docs/ .  i wanted to know if it could be use in native mobile.

Comment: You want to know if you could use bootstrap in native code or there is an Android version of bootstrap you can use?

Comment: both ? i want to know if there is an andriod version of bootstrap and if not does anyone apply twitter bootstrap to native android ?

Comment: Twitter bootstrap is written in js so you can't apply this to native android.

Comment: Anyway, Android uses material design so please follow their guideline here, https://developer.android.com/design/index.html. For material design libraries, you can have a look at this link for a start, https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-ui